# Is formatting my partitions the same thing as wiping my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I am formatting my partitions, and I want to know if this is the same as formatting or wiping my hard drive. I messed with my partitions too much, and I heard this will make my computer unstable. Will this fix this? If so, how can I merge my partitions into one once they are done formatting?

BTW, I have not yet installed Ubuntu on my computer. When I do, will there be an option to format my drive? And will this do the same thing?

Comment: You really have to do better than "I heard that doing <something vague> can <vaguely cause harm>" or your question is nonsense.

Comment: Erasing partitions is like formatting a part of the drive without actually deleting the data there. Like when you delete a file, it's still there and recoverable (under special circumstances)

Answer (score 3):

Wiping generally means to overwrite a partition/drive with other data (nulls, zeros, random) to completely destroy all data and prevent recovery. Formatting is to put a new filesystem on a partition, possibly on top of an old partition leaving the old data still recoverable but normally unseen.

The Ubuntu installer should let you pick a partition to format & install to, and probably partitions for /tmp, home, etc...

I don't know what "messing" you did with your drive so I couldn't guess if it's bad or not, but if you do a fresh install of Ubuntu you'll probably want to format it's partition to a ubuntu-friendly filesystem (fat32 or ntfs aren't optimal for linux) it should be as stable as completely wiping your drive, the rest of the drive is just data (as long as there's nothing running before Ubuntu)

If you want, you can run a Ubuntu live usb/cd/dvd (the same one you'll use to install Ubuntu) and run `gparted` (can install it with `sudo apt-get install gparted` if it's not already there) and resize or delete or move/make new partitions. There isn't really a merge. But backup any data you want to keep first. Actually it's safest to backup data before installing Ubuntu too.